# Storing Integer Value in Character Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

Hello I am trying to create a tick Tack Toe Game For my College Project, 
The Board size of the game needs to be GENERIC using 2D array in C++. 
So I'm having trouble while initializing Default numbers(Places) identifier in an array

```
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            Boards[i][j] = initial++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (Boards[i][j] < 10) cout << " " << Boards[i][j] << "   |   ";
            else cout << Boards[i][j] << "   |   ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
```

As the variable 'initial' is a integer and i have to increment it in loop.I am quite not sure how to save it in char array (BOARD) Board needs to be char to display X,O

Comment: What does initial even represent? Why do you need to increment it?

Comment: Initial is the default values The Default values need to be 0-Size*Size; @Mureinik

Comment: why don't you leave it 0 without incrementing it ?  By the way can you confirm that SIZE is a const ?

Comment: Why would i want to set it 0 while i want to store 0 - N numbers in the array this is how the board is supposed to look like. http://prntscr.com/ff8po6 Yep SIZE is a CONST

Comment: What issue are you having?  It looks like you successfully stored the integer value in your char array.  You just have to make sure the integer is never going to be above 127, because then it will not fit in a char.

Comment: @DavidGrayson It Stores ASCII Equivalent Character or a Junk Value instead of the Actual Number. I do know that the number needs to be in single quotation to store  in Character Type Array or Variable.

Comment: If there is a way i can get that integer in single quotation that might work out.

Comment: The code you posted looks fine.  Please post the full code that is exhibiting issues for you.  If you are talking about ASCII like that, it makes me think you are just printing the array incorrectly.  See [mcve].

Comment: @FaqahatFareed It _sounds like_ you've found a problem and are blaming the wrong code, how are you printing the values of the `Board` array?

Comment: I have Pasted whole Code, Kindly Look, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have posted the full code, I can see a problem on this line and the other one like it:

```
cout << Boards[i][j] << "   |   ";
```

Since the type of `Boards[i][j]` is a `char`, the C++ standard library will just send that char to your terminal, and the terminal will try to interpret it as an ASCII character.  You need to cast it to an `int` first so that the C++ standard library will format it properly for you:

```
cout << (int)Boards[i][j] << "   |   ";
```